# is it ironic that on a site about christianity opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion is bad practice?

Tags: discussion, irony

I was looking at a question that was closed for this reason and chuckled to myself.

Although I guess this site has to follow the stack exchange dogma like any other site in the family.

Comment: Ironic is [philosophy.se] discouraging opinion, debate, and extended discussion... But that is the nature of the software. This is not a forum.

Comment: [What word means what many people think 'ironic' means?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6618)

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/irony

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it isn't! This site isn't Christianity the faith, it is Christianity the Q&A site. It can't possibly encompass every aspect of the former... but may help us understand it it better: at least as valid an approach to Chrisitan thought as open discussion. Fortunately, there are alredy plenty of other sites where you can debate all you like, but none that can provide a Q&A service like the one we're building here. Hopefully, Christianity.SE will provide a refreshing alternative to debate if that is what you're looking for. If not, then wouldn't it be good if there was somewhere where you could always ask for a forum recommendation?